# QListWidget sharing the same model

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

If I understood the concept of the Qt models correct, then I can have multiple views, sharing the same model, so that when data is updated in the model, all views using it, will also update their view accordingly right?

Now I have multiple widgets in my application, which should have individual selections, but they should operate on the same underlying data. So when a row is added in one of the panels, the others should be able to display this new row as well.

Since the `QListWidget` provides all the features that I need, there would be no point in writing my own model and use it with a `QListView`. But I realized that `QListWidget` doesn't allow me to change the model, because the `setModel()`method is made private. 
So is there some way that I can achieve this, without the need of writing a full model on my own?  I'm rather new to Qt so maybe there is a ready made general purpose model, that I can use? But so far I haven't found one.

Comment: You don't have to write your own model. There is for example [`QStandardItemModel`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) and [QStringListModel](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use QListWidget to set your own model which is not possible.
You are better off using the MVC pattern the QT imposes. You can refer [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq10-mvc.html) on how to use the MVC pattern. This way would be more manageable and correct. Also you can make of the `QStandardItemModel` or the more general `QAbstractListModel` or `QStringListModel` model for lists. You can refer [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) for more details

But to answer your question yes they is a hack you can use.
Create a `QListWidget` and treat that widget as your model.
For other views create a `QListView` and set the model that is returned by the `QListWidget`
.
For e.g. refer

```
QAbstractItemModel* model = listWidget->model();

listView->setModel(model);
listView_2->setModel(model);
```

Then you can use the listWidget as your model. Any operation (add/delete) performed on the listWidget will also affect the listView and listView_2.

I am still of the opinion that instead of the hack creating your own model would be better and more correct.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of such a hack as well, but I don't really like it. I'm using now the `QListView` with the `QStringListModel`.